# How to prevent repeated values from submitting?

Tags: symfony, validation, doctrine-orm, unique, api-platform.com

How to validate whether a submitted value is not a repeated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I mentioned in comments - you just need to add [unique constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) to that field in database.